# XLST to insert HTML snippet into resulting HTML document

Tags: xslt, docbook

I have a docBook 4.4 XML file which is a user guide. I can use the (Maven) tools to convert that to HTML, PDF no problem. The problem i have is to insert an small HTML code snippet into the resulting HTML file.

I would like to add the following HTML snippet:

```
<xsl:template name="xxxxxxx">
  <img src="images/pdfdoc.gif">PDF</img>
</xsl:template>
```

The resulting HTML code looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./hilfeKMV.css">
<meta name="generator" content="DocBook XSL Stylesheets V1.76.0">
<meta name="date" content="10/12/2011">
</head>
<body bgcolor="white" text="black" link="#0000FF" vlink="#840084"
    alink="#0000FF">
    <div lang="de" class="book"
        title="Title">
        <div class="titlepage">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <h1 class="title">
                        <a name="d0e1"></a>title
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="toc">
            <p>
                <b>TOC</b>
            </p>
```

I would like to insert the HTML snippet before the `<div class="toc">`...So the question is how to solve this? I'm using docbook 1.76.0
I think there must be something like the following to solve that but i don't know how to set call-template etc. ?

```
   <xsl:template name="xxxxxxx">
      <xsl:variable name="top-anchor">
        <xsl:call-template name="object.id">
          <xsl:with-param name="object" select="/*[1]"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>
      <img src="images/pdfdoc.gif">PDF</img>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: So based on your input you would like to have something like : <img src="images/pdfdoc.gif">PDF</img> as a sibling of <div class="toc"> albeit before the div?

Comment: You need to make Docbook output the result in wellformed XML (XHTML) -- probably use Docbook for XSLT 2.0 and just set the output method to XHTML -- and then you can apply a modification of the identity rule to just add a new element.

Comment: @FailedDev No. I would like to have it separately. But of course i can put something around the <img..> like <div>...</div> Is not problem. But i need it to have it before class="toc" div and after the div class="titlepage".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the correct location to insert the code i need.
In the titlepage.templates.xsl file i found the correct solution. I just taken the snippet from the titlepage.templates.xsl and enhanced it like the following:

```
<xsl:template name="book.titlepage.separator">
    <div class="subsubtile">
        <div class="pdflink">
            <a href="./xxxx.pdf" title="Hilfeseite als PDF-Dokument">
                <img src="images/pdfdoc.gif" border="0" alt="Hilfeseite als PDF-Dokument" />
                <br />
                PDF
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<div class="toc">` element is generated by the template named "make.toc", which is called by "division.toc" (in autotoc.xsl). In order to output something immediately before this `<div>`, you can override the "division.toc" template in your customization layer. Just copy the original template and add your code, like this:

```
<xsl:template name="division.toc">
  <xsl:param name="toc-context" select="."/>
  <xsl:param name="toc.title.p" select="true()"/>

  <img src="images/pdfdoc.gif" alt="PDF"/>    <!-- Your stuff here -->

  <xsl:call-template name="make.toc">
    ...
    ...
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```